# How to define two where clauses with Or between them using Fluent nHibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I want to map a property only if a specific column is eual to one of two values,
currently I have tried this:

```
HasMany<Event>(u => u.Events)
    .KeyColumn("Id")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .OrderBy("OrderByDate desc")
    .Where(e => e.Status == Status.New || e.Status == Status.Old);
```

but I get an exception "Unable to convert expression to SQL"

how can I create a mapping with two where clauses with an OR operator between them ?

EDIT: I don't want to use SQL in my mapping, I want to use lambda expression (if possible...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the implementation does handle some things but it is far from complete (especially `ExpressionType.OrElse`/`BinaryExpression` is not handled). You have to write sql yourself or enhance the implementation of class `ExpressionToSql`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to enhance the current implementation